# Converting SQL to MariaDB statement

Tags: sql, datetime, mariadb

I’m trying to convert the below to MariaDB in order to get the next relevant date from today’s date.

The below SQL will get the next Sunday from the specified date

```
DECLARE @NextDayID INT;
SET @NextDayID = 1; -- Next Sunday
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, ((@NextDayID + 5) % 7), GETDATE()) / 7) * 7 + 7, ((@NextDayID + 5) % 7)) AS NextDay
```

Comment: MariaDB supports SQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use date arithmetic:

```
select curdate() + interval (7 - dayofweek(curdate()) +  1) % 7 day
```